# Javascript ENV VARS not being parsed in Vite Config

Tags: javascript, dotenv, vite

Using Vite in a Laravel app.

In my `.env` file I have a var set in an env key like so:

```
APP_DOMAIN=example.test
...

VITE_DOMAIN="${APP_DOMAIN}"
```

In my `vite.config.js` I have imported `Dotenv` and run `Dotenv.config()` and it's picking up the keys from `.env` just fine, but it's not parsing the dynamic variable that are set.

When I run `vite` I'm getting the following error:

```sh
error when starting dev server:
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ${APP_DOMAIN}
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:71:26)
```

Is there something I can do, a package to add or config to change that will allow `Dotenv` to parse these variables?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Vite allows to use an environment param to declare another. This should work in your case

```
VITE_DOMAIN=example.test
```